# Franz messaging app - untrusted CA

Tags: ssl, certificates, franz

I've recently moved from Mint to Ubuntu and encountered a problem.

I'm using Franz to manage my multiple messenger accounts. One of them is my employer's Rocket Chat.

At first Rocket Chat didn't work, returning a message

`The URL you've entered is not a valid server`

On Mint I added the CA bundle to the system truststore it started working as it should.

When trying to do it on Ubuntu it still doesn't. The certificates work when added to browsers.

I know it's a long shot, but has anybody encountered this specific problem? If not, do you know what truststore is Franz using, or maybe how can I enable debug mode that would allow me to understand what exactly is going on?